# string.find() doesn't return -1

Tags: c++

The code below is simple. As I know, if string::find() didn't find matches it returns -1. But for some reasons the code below doesn't work. Everytime I run this code I get endless loop. Thank you for help!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    text = "asdasd ijk asdasd";
    string toReplace = "ijk";
    cout<<text<<endl;
    int counter = 0;
    while ( text.find(toReplace) != -1)
        counter++;

    cout<<counter<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Methinks some time spent reading [the documentation of std::basic_string::find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) would likely do *wonders* in learning how something works.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to use while ( text.find(toReplace) != string::npos ) but I still get endless loop :(

Comment: Did you try doing anything in that while-body besides increment a meaningless counter? It was there the first check, time-alone isn't going to do it any favors. Perhaps change where you start looking after each successful hit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aside from the other answers which are completely correct, I just wanted to add that your while loop would have produced an endless loop anyway. For example:

```
while(text.find(toReplace) != std::string::npos)
    counter++;
```

will be an endless loop because it will keep trying to find the `toReplace` string in `text` and it will always find it (that's because find starts from the beginning of the string each time). This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thank you! That's why I get endless loop everytime!

Comment: @user2167403 ha ha, is this new paradigm or design pattern?

Answer (score 8):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if the searched substring is not found, not `-1`. The exact value of `npos` is implementation-defined, so use `npos`, as in

```
while ( text.find(toReplace) != std::string::npos)
```

Come to think of it, `find` couldn't return -1 even if it wanted to because the return type of find is specified to be `std::size_t` which is an *unsigned* type.

Additionally, find will **always** search for the **first** occurrence of the substring, no matter how many times you call it. If you want to iterate through all the occurrences you should use the overload of `find` which takes a second parameter - the position from which to start searching.

Comment: `npos` *is* `-1` (converted to `size_type`). `-1` is arguably less stylish, but not incorrect.

Comment: "*is* -1" and "is -1 converted to size_t" are different things :)

Comment: True, but it's certainly not implementation-defined, and comparing the `size_type` result of `find` with `-1` will always give the same result as comparing with `npos`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Interesting to know, I didn't know the value of npos was specified by the standard

Answer (score 5):

Whoever told you this or wherever you read it, it lied to you.

If `std::string::find` fails, it returns `std::string::npos`, which is not `-1`.

You should check the documentation about such things, when you're not sure.

So, your `while` will be something like:

```
while ( std::string::npos != text.find(toReplace) )
```

---

Regarding your comment:

> UPDATE: I tried to use while ( text.find(toReplace) != string::npos ) but I still get endless loop :( – user2167403 10 secs ago

You should really learn to read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). Use a variable to store the last result of `std::string::find` (different from `std::string::npos`) and use `std::string::find`'s second parameter - `pos` ( by passing value - `last_match_position + 1`).

Omitting the second parameter, `std::string::find` always starts from the beginning of the string, which causes the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you provided `text` variable contains substring "ijk" which is stored in the `toReplace` variable. As long as in while cycle neither `text` or `toReplace` variables are changed, find method will always return not a -1 value which is the condition for while cycle to continue.

As already metioned in other comments you should check not for -1 but for `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 0):

It does help to read the manual page (string::npos is the answer).

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/